# How to generate UIImages in a hexagon "map" view

Tags: swift, user-interface

I'm building an app where I want to display profilePictures of people "near you" in a hexagon beehive style.

The full beehive should be draggable, like google maps for example.

My question is if this is something I can do with just using UIKit, or if it would be easier to use UIKit and SpriteKit together.

I hope someone could point me at the right direction and or have some ideas on how this could be made. Thank you for your time!

**Update:**
Just to make my question a bit more clear.

[This is how my view looks like atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IaWa.jpg)

[And this is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXRKg.png)

In the first image I´ve just set the X and Y pos of the UIImage center middle.

I want to create some sort of function that can get an array of different profilePics and then put the out in this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIKit` alone can do the job: you should try to setup a mask with `CALayer` on a `UIImageView` for instance.

The draggable behavior thing can be achieved either with a `UIScrollView` by adding and arranging all your image subviews in it, or with a `UICollectionView` with a custom flow, but it may be much harder to set up.

For the hexagon views, you'll find here an interesting example you can adapt for your usage: http://sapandiwakar.in/make-hexagonal-view-on-ios/

Here is an adaption of Sapan Diwakar solution in Swift 4.2 and using extensions:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    convenience init(roundedPolygonPathInRect rect: CGRect, lineWidth: CGFloat, sides: NSInteger, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0, rotationOffset: CGFloat = 0) {
        self.init()

        let theta: CGFloat = 2.0 * CGFloat.pi / CGFloat(sides) // How much to turn at every corner
        let width = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)        // Width of the square

        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + width / 2.0, y: rect.origin.y + width / 2.0)

        // Radius of the circle that encircles the polygon
        // Notice that the radius is adjusted for the corners, that way the largest outer
        // dimension of the resulting shape is always exactly the width - linewidth
        let radius = (width - lineWidth + cornerRadius - (cos(theta) * cornerRadius)) / 2.0

        // Start drawing at a point, which by default is at the right hand edge
        // but can be offset
        var angle = CGFloat(rotationOffset)

        let corner = CGPoint(x: center.x + (radius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle), y: center.y + (radius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
        move(to: CGPoint(x: corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle + theta), y: corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle + theta)))

        for _ in 0 ..< sides {
            angle += theta

            let corner = CGPoint(x: center.x + (radius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle), y: center.y + (radius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
            let tip = CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(angle), y: center.y + radius * sin(angle))
            let start = CGPoint(x: corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle - theta), y: corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle - theta))
            let end = CGPoint(x: corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle + theta), y: corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle + theta))

            addLine(to: start)
            addQuadCurve(to: end, controlPoint: tip)
        }

        close()
    }
}

extension UIImageView {
    func setupHexagonMask(lineWidth: CGFloat, color: UIColor, cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedPolygonPathInRect: bounds, lineWidth: lineWidth, sides: 6, cornerRadius: cornerRadius, rotationOffset: CGFloat.pi / 2.0).cgPath

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path
        mask.lineWidth = lineWidth
        mask.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        mask.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.mask = mask

        let border = CAShapeLayer()
        border.path = path
        border.lineWidth = lineWidth
        border.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        border.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

And then you can just use it like that:

```
let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 300, height: 300))
image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
image.image = UIImage(named: "lenna.png")
image.setupHexagonMask(lineWidth: 5.0, color: .white, cornerRadius: 20.0)

view.addSubview(image)
```

**EDIT**: As I told you, the easiest way is to use a `UIScrollView` to display your map, and with simple math you can display your hexagons the way you want.

Here is a small example you must adapt to match your requirements. For example you should be extra careful with performance. This example should not be used as is, if you have many images, you should load them on the fly and remove them when you don't show them. And you can even think using a background rendering if it takes too much fps...

[image: Example with the same image, here lenna.png]

Assuming `view` is a `UIScrollView`:

```
let hexaDiameter : CGFloat = 150
let hexaWidth = hexaDiameter * sqrt(3) * 0.5
let hexaWidthDelta = (hexaDiameter - hexaWidth) * 0.5
let hexaHeightDelta = hexaDiameter * 0.25
let spacing : CGFloat = 5

let rows = 10
let firstRowColumns = 6

view.contentSize = CGSize(width: spacing + CGFloat(firstRowColumns) * (hexaWidth + spacing),
                          height: spacing + CGFloat(rows) * (hexaDiameter - hexaHeightDelta + spacing) + hexaHeightDelta)

for y in 0..<rows {
    let cellsInRow = y % 2 == 0 ? firstRowColumns : firstRowColumns - 1
    let rowXDelta = y % 2 == 0 ? 0.0 : (hexaWidth + spacing) * 0.5
    for x in 0..<cellsInRow {
        let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: rowXDelta + CGFloat(x) * (hexaWidth + spacing) + spacing - hexaWidthDelta,
                                              y: CGFloat(y) * (hexaDiameter - hexaHeightDelta + spacing) + spacing,
                                              width: hexaDiameter,
                                              height: hexaDiameter))
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.image = UIImage(named: "lenna.png")
        image.setupHexagonMask(lineWidth: 5.0, color: .white, cornerRadius: 10.0)
        view.addSubview(image)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have stumbled upon this example before and this is the solution I ended up using to make my UIImage hexagon.

unfortunately this is just a part of my problem, but it didn't clearly show through my question. So I updated it now and hopefully it makes more sense in what I struggle with. 

Thank you.

Comment: I edited my post to add a small example with a `UIScrollView`. If it works for you don't hesitate to upvote and validate the answer.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for your time!